# reference of pointer as a function argument

Tags: c++, pointers

```
void SMatrix::setElement(int i, int j, double data)
{
            Node* temp = new Node(data, i, j, NULL, NULL);
            addNode(temp,(*this->rowsArr[i])); // this->rowsArr[i] is also Node*
}

void SMatrix::addNode(Node* temp, Node& list)
{

    if (&list == NULL)
        list = *temp;
}
```

so i try to copy temp to list as a reference, but the copy here is (i think) as a value, and whhen the function end, nothing change and the list remain NULL.
how can i copy it by reference and save the temp in list?

Comment: The address of a variable can never be null; why are you testing for that?

Answer (score 3):

The check `if (&list == NULL)` never fires since the address of an object is never a null pointer.

What you probably mean to do is pass the *pointer* by reference:

```
void SMatrix::addNode(Node * temp, Node * & list)
{
    if (list == NULL) { list = temp; }
}
```

Then call it:

```
    Node* temp = new Node(data, i, j, NULL, NULL);
    addNode(temp, this->rowsArr[i]);
```

This will of course leak memory if the node didn't get added! (So perhaps you should add `else { delete temp; }` to `addNode`.)

Comment: Also for a purpose like this (`rowsArr`), your'd better try `std::vector` instead of managing dynamic memory by yourself which is error prone.

Comment: @Jaege: Well, yes, I assume that almost every aspect of the OP's design is very broken. But this isn't a code review...